# Having trouble with PowerShell recurse in VB6 folder

Tags: powershell, build, scripting, vb6

I am using a script to build VB6 files. Until now every folder was hard coded which is not the best solution, so I try to change the script to find and build .vbp file from the folder. Unfortunately it isn't even executed. The code is below. `$outputfile` is the logs file.

```bsh
Get-ChildItem $folder -Include *.vbp -Recurse | foreach ($_) {
    & vb6.exe /out $outputFile $_.FullName /make 
}
```

Comment: what do you need to do exactly .

Comment: remove `($_)`, it's invalid syntax

Comment: @wOxxOm No, it isn't. It's just pointless.

Comment: i want to search in the folder and subfolders of $folder for .vbp file and then build them and keep logs in the $outpuFile

Comment: @Vangelis What isn't executed? The `Get-ChildItem`? The `foreach`? The `vb6.exe`? Is `vb6.exe` in your `$env:PATH`? What do you see when you replace the `& vb6.exe ...` statement with just `$_.FullName`? Are you getting errors? What does the log say?

Comment: Get-ChildItem is executed, i get the list of the files when i replace the & vb6.exe, vb6.exe is executed as before with hard coded path everything worked fine, the log file is empty.

Comment: Does `$outputFile` or `$_.Fullname` contain spaces? I could see vb6.exe having issues parsing that. If you were to type it out manually I bet you would use quotes!

Comment: No neither of them contains spaces.

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be issues with the parsing the $_.fullname without enclosing in $(). Try this:

```
Get-ChildItem $folder -Include *.vbp -Recurse | foreach {
    & vb6.exe /out $outputFile $($_.FullName) /make 
}
```